# shortening MongoDBObject Conversion

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

one thing I came across is the boilerplate code when querying in a  mongodb :

```
def findPagesWithGreaterId(pageid: String, limit: Int): List[Page] =
    findAsListSortedLimit(MongoDBObject("_id" -> MongoDBObject("$gt" -> new ObjectId(pageid))), MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1), limit)
```

Is there a nice way of shortening the queries like in the above example?

(implicits are not handy i guess)

is there a common approach to it?

thanks in advance,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a type alias just to shorten class names:

```
type DBO = MongoDBObject
```

or in a similar way rename a class on import:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.{MongoDBObject => DBO}
```

I don't like these solutions much. A better thing to do would be to use [Rogue](https://github.com/foursquare/rogue). It not just reads better, it's actually much more typesafe. The only downside is that you have to define your DB classes first before you can query, but once you do, your query would look like:

```
Pages.where(_.id gt new ObjectId(pageid)).orderAsc(_.id).limit(1)
```

or something like that :).

Check [here](https://github.com/foursquare/rogue/blob/master/rogue-lift/src/test/scala/com/foursquare/rogue/QueryTest.scala) for more examples.